# How to Minimize Phone Call Screen

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm writing an application, that enables the user to call emergency services. I start the phone call using `PhoneCallTask` and the application starts calling as expected. When the call starts, user is presented with the following screen:

[image: Phone call screen]

If the user presses the 'Windows' button, (marked with green circle on picture below), the phone call screen minimizes (green rectangle on the picture below)

[image]

***Is it possible to minimize the phone call screen in the same way as above programmatically?*** The thing is, user is supposed to have access to features like location (Navigation to another xaml page) during the phone call so I cannot have a full screen phone call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. When you launch any Launcher you navigate away from your app and have no control over whats going on. You can always navigate back to your app though, with the back button and continue with what you want to do there.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case, since I could find anything on the Web. Thanks anyway!